# Kafka error: Unknown partition (unknown_partition)

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, librdkafka

I am using https://github.com/zendesk/racecar (which uses https://github.com/appsignal/rdkafka-ruby under the hood, a Ruby wrapper for https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/) to consume a Kafka stream and every now and then I receive this error `Local: Unknown partition (unknown_partition)`

```
"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rdkafka-0.8.1/lib/rdkafka/consumer.rb:339:in `store_offset'", 
"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/racecar-2.3.0/lib/racecar/consumer_set.rb:51:in `store_offset'"
```

This error seem to be raised when calling `rd_kafka_offset_store`, responsible to `store offset of a message to be used in the next commit of this consumer`.

Inspecting logs with `config.log_level = "debug"` looks like the error above always is preceded by:

```
rdkafka: [thrd:sasl_ssl://a1-abc-d1er1.eu-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2]: sasl_ssl://a1-abc-d1er1.eu-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2: Disconnected (after 3600185ms in state UP)

(try 1/10): Error for topic subscription #<struct Racecar::Consumer::Subscription topic="my.topic", start_from_beginning=true, max_bytes_per_partition=1048576, additional_config={}>: Local: Broker transport failure (transport)
```

First time using Kafka here and I don't have an idea what might be.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error `Local: Unknown partition` because of no read access rights to that topic on broker. Hope this will help somebody.